Windows user and machine credentials
In a Windows computer added to a domain, where are user/machine credentials stored which are used for network authentication?

Credential secrets are stored in the registry:
HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets
A number of tools exist for extracting this information. This is also the location used by the shutdown command to automatically logon the previous user and restart applications that were open. Note that the default permissions do not allow read or list except for system.
https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1003/004/
